# HttpPatchAsync working on windows but not Linux

Tags: .net, linux, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an endpoint in a .Net Core API running in a linux container

```
[HttpPatch] // inside controller called Customer
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchAsync([FromBody] TestObject entity)
{
    return Ok(await _service.PatchAsync(entity));
}
```

The Poco

```
public class TestObject 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

from my Blazor app I have the following code to update the entity

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateEntity(TestObject entity)
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await httpClient.PatchAsync(@"http://someserverpath:5000/api/v1/Customer", content))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(apiResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having when I run the code locally on windows 10 it works. When I run this code inside a Linux docker container I get the following exception

> Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character
> encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: What is running on Linux? The API? What does the API return? I'm guessing it's returning an error message which is why you should be checking the HTTP response code when using HttpClient.

Comment: The api is always running in a linux container. The app is running from visual studio on windows 10 and this works, When i run the app locally in a linux container i get the exception

Comment: the api does not return a response code i get a fatal error (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException) inside blazor.server.js:21 so i am guessing the its happening before the api is hit

Comment: the only difference is linux vs windows

Comment: I'm using PATCh with Blazor Wasm on a Mac and have no problem. I don't use JSON.NET either, as HTTP Patch has nothing to do with the JSON serializer. Your own code simply serializes the content, which can be handled just fine by System.Text.Json. The exception complains about the *json string*. Where is this error thrown? On the client? Server? What is the *full* exception text? What is the full text?

Comment: Do you have Blazor Server or Blazor Wasm?

Comment: You can absolutely check the HTTP response code inside the `UpdateEntity` method. It's just `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` to check if the call worked.

Comment: i am using Blazor Server and I can confirm that the Api is not being hit

Comment: Why are you using ```StringContent``` for JSON? You shouldn't do all this stuff manually. Same with ```ReadAsStringAsync```. Why do you read it as string, if you know it's ```bool```. And check the status code before reading the content. Your app may even not reach the API, and you wouldn't know.

Comment: I was using StringContent as i found it in a sample on how to use HttpClient. This does work fine on windows, is this not the correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateEntity(TestObject entity)
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    using var response = await httpClient.PatchAsync(@"http://someserverpath:5000/api/v1/Customer", content);
        
    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(apiResponse);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong when.... See inner excpetion.", new Exception(apiResponse));
    }
}
```

You most likely received a non successful response and need to return the exception thrown by the API. Handle it the way you normally would in your solution